# Is it posible to create a pwa with screen overlay acces for android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ember.js

**Hey there!**

I'm currently working on a new chat webapp for android using *emberjs, cordova and firebase*.

The only problem i encounter is that i can't find anything about the screen overlay access for android.

Does anyone know if this is possible in some kind of way for a PWA?

Regards.